# Issues with {displayName} of JUnit5 @RepeatedTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, junit5

It's evening here in Nigeria and I am facing a problem while studying JUnit 5 Repeated tests:

```
@RepeatedTest(value=4, name= "{displayName} running: {currentRepetition}/{totalRepetitions}")
@DisplayName(”RepeatedTest”)
void repeatedTest() {
        //removed for brevity.
}
```

In the above code, unlike the other placeholders, {displayName} isn't resolved. Why please?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put value in `@DisplayName` annotation. Try this:

```
@RepeatedTest(value=4, name= "{displayName} running: {currentRepetition}/{totalRepetitions}")
@DisplayName("MyTestClass")
void repeatedTest() {
        //removed for brevity.
}
```

Documentation for `@DisplayName` annotation: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayName.html

Comment: I'm so sorry bro. My bad. it was a typo. I've edited the question. It's not resolved even with the value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's your issue, but in your example the cotta you have used in @DisplayName is wrong. I just copied your code to test and I need to change it.

But, changing it, your code is ok and {displayName} has been resolved fine.

Please let us know your JUnit version and your import session. Copy and paste your maven dependency here.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot. Okay then. I’ll bring feedback.

Comment: Hello. I'm using Gradle and these are my dependencies:

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'

Comment: then my import: org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;